# What is the maximum Electric Current output from an iPhone in Host Mode?

Tags: ios, iphone, mfi

What is the maximum Electric Current output from an iPhone in Host Mode via the Lighting Port? I know that this seems like a question unrelated to software, but it has to do with Apple's MFI guidelines and specs. I can not find the MFI guidelines because I am not an MFI member. So this question is for iOS developers that know MFI guidelines (or can look it up). MFI has Host Mode guidelines and specs on how to operate an external camera, game controller, etc. In these guidelines I assume there is something about voltage and maximum electric current that can be supplied to the external device. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: You are asking people to violate the terms of their agreement with Apple under the MFi program

Comment: Sorry, I did not know that these guidelines were confidential. 1000's of manufacturers have the guidelines. Anyway, I fixed the question to limit my question only on the regulated electric current.